# $.csv undefined even after importing jquery-csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I am trying to parse csv file to arrays using this [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) plugin but when checking log for $.csv is says undefined. However, when I copy and execute the code from the plugin directly in the console, $.csv works. I even tried method jquery's getScript() method to import the jquery-csv directly to my custom script but it shows undefined.

```
$.getScript("../js/jquery-csv.js"); console.log($.csv);
```

Also tried added this in head and it shows up in Chrome developer tools
`script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.9/jquery.csv.min.js') included this in the head of the page. It shows up in head through chrome devtools`

P.S - Using pug template engine

Comment: We can't magically know what your attempt to import it looked like, and thus what was wrong with it. Why don't you show us? More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We need to see some code you used. Help us help you.

Comment: `$.getScript("../js/jquery-csv.js");
    console.log($.csv);`

Comment: Why not just use a standard `<script` tag? Also bear in mind that you're running `console.log($.csv);` before the script is loaded. getScript is async and provides a callback function for you to use to run code once it's complete. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ So `$.getScript( "../js/jquery-csv.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log($.csv);
  })`

Comment: `script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.9/jquery.csv.min.js')` included this in the head of the page. It shows up in head through chrome devtools

Comment: Ok so if you did that you don't need the getScript as well.

Comment: When that was not working, I tried getScript()

Comment: But that's invalid markup. It should be `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.9/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>` . Not sure where you got that other syntax from? The syntax for script tags is clearly documented in many places online, and/or you can look at the source of any other website to get an example. And also scr should be src

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I am using pug template engine

Comment: Well you still made a typo with scr instead of src. Detail is important.

Comment: I changed that but its still undefined. I have been swapping different versions of the plugin hoping this was version related.

Comment: @ADyson Could it be because I am using node js and it has other csv parsing modules, like fast-csv, its causing a conflict? If that is the case, what can be done to avoid such conflicts?

Comment: I don't understand - if you're loading this into your browser page then nodeJS is not relevant to that - it runs on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use direct `$.csv` after run `getScript` function. because maybe it take some time to load js but `console.log` statement run after `getScript` statment run . so you have to try this ..

```
$.getScript("../js/jquery-csv.js",function(){
    console.log($.csv);
});
```

Comment: That worked! But I still don't understand why adding the script in the head itself doesn't work considering I am waiting for the document to be ready before executing $.csv.

Comment: The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed.